# Send email with attachment in Android. Works on Gmail but not on Outlook

Tags: android, email, outlook, gmail

So from my Android app I can send emails with attachment on Gmail. On outlook looks like it is attaching the file (.txt), but when I open the mail there is no attached file.

This is my code:

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Uri uriFileToShare = Uri.fromFile(file);
emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, file.getName());
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriFileToShare);
this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, activity.getString(R.string.send)+" "+file.getName()+" "+activity.getString(R.string.by_email)),code);
```

I have tried different solutions but no result.

The file of course exists and is not empty. As I said, on Gmail is correctly attached.

Any idea?

Comment: The MIME type for plain text is `text/plain`, not `plain/text`.

Comment: Is there any possibility someone solved this?

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me on outlook file attachment.

```
public static void emailLog(Context context) {
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("text/html");
    String filePath = fileDir + "/" + fileName;
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{""});
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
    File recordingFile = new File(filePath);
    Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(recordingFile);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri);
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Some text..."));
}
```